# Server control event does not fire correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, postback, servercontrols

First of all, I found a few similar questions. One of them is *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832688/asp-net-page-with-multiple-custom-controls-implementing-ipostbackeventhandler)* , which does not have correct answer.

I'm writing custom server control, which has *Text* property and *Click* event. Everything woks fine (*Click* event is firing and *sender* object has correct value), **but only if I use it only in one place on the page**.

This example works fine (if *SimpleControl1.Text* has value *"First control"*, in response I'm receiving correct value):

```
protected void SimpleControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SimpleControl sc = sender as SimpleControl;
        if(sc != null)
        {
            Response.Write(sc.Text);
        }
    }
```

But if I add second control on the same page (*SimpleControl2* with text *"Second Control"*), my first control's *Click* event will no longer work:

```
    protected void SimpleControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SimpleControl sc = sender as SimpleControl;
        if (sc != null)
        {
            Response.Write(sc.Text);
        }
    }
```

So if I click on first control, I'm receiving *"Second control"* text.

I think I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

How to resolve this problem?

Here is my simple Web control:

```
public class SimpleControl : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private static readonly object EventClick = new object();

    protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler eventHandler = (EventHandler)Events[SimpleControl.EventClick];
        if (eventHandler != null) { eventHandler(this, e); }
    }

    public event EventHandler Click
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(EventClick, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(EventClick, value); }
    }

    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        object state = base.SaveControlState();
        return new object[] { state, Text };
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object state)
    {
        object[] states = state as object[];
        if (states != null)
        {
            base.LoadControlState(states[0]);
            Text = (string)states[1];
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ClientID);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, this.UniqueID);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Click"));

        writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
        writer.Write(Text);
        writer.RenderEndTag(); 

        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

markap

```
<cc1:SimpleControl ID="SimpleControl1" runat="server" 
Text="First control" OnClick="SimpleControl1_Click"  />
<cc1:SimpleControl ID="SimpleControl2" runat="server" 
Text="Second Control" OnClick="SimpleControl2_Click" />
```

p.s. I also removed *Control State* support but it didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: you can use ref of that control

Comment: I think **object state = base.SaveControlState()** state may be null.

Comment: @minhcat_vo Control state cannot produce this issue. I completely removed control state support and changed to ViewState, but it still fires second event.

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze - the edit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/2691285?&_suid=13760783519570504270959020197) is in no way a valid edit; please be more careful when reviewing suggested edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line from `OnInit`:

```
Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
```

The msdn for this method states:

> Only one server control can be registered per page request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequiresraiseevent.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How are you binding your events? Can you show markup also? I would assume that something odd is happening when you're binding the event, and somehow you've bound the second event to the first control, or something along those lines.

Comment: No this does not produces the issue. I used this control in DataList as template control and only last added control's event is firing. Even when I click on any other control.

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Crwydryn guess is pretty much spot on if the feature is what you after (or somewhat similar). You can just bind to SimpleControl_Click for both or more controls. Posting your markup will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **object state = base.SaveControlState()** state may be null. According to MSDN

> Returns the server control's current state. If there is no state associated with the control, this method returns null.

```
public override object SaveControlState()
{
    object obj = base.SaveControlState();
    // Your problem is here
    // return new object[] { obj, Text };
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
    {
       if (obj != null)
       {
           return new object[] { obj, Text };
       }
       else
       {
           return Text;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
public override void LoadControlState(object state)
{
    if (state != null)
    {
        object obj = state as object[];
        if (obj != null)
        {
            base.LoadControlState(obj[0]);
            Text = (string)obj[1];
        }
        else
        {
            if (state is string)
            {
                 Text = (string)state;
            }
            else
            {
                 base.LoadControlState(state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```